# displaying another frame by clicking a button on the current frame

Tags: java, frame

I need a functionality where clicking a button in frame which is currently being displayed, displays a new frame with new contents after removing the contents of the first frame. How should I do it?

I tried doing something like this

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test extends Frame implements ActionListener   {
   Button b1;
   public test()    {
    Panel p1 = new Panel();
    p1.setLayout ( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER) );
    p1.add (b1 = new Button("click"));
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    add(p1);
   }
public static void main (String[] args)     {
    Frame f1 = new test();
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.setSize(400,400);
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae)    {
    String str = ae.getActionCommand();
    if (ae.getSource() instanceof Button)   {
        if ( str.equals("click") )  {
            f1.setVisible(false);
            Frame f2 = new test();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Waht do you mean with "removing content"? Show us some code, what you tried so far please

Comment: i know its quite erroneous, but I'm a newbie and wish to learn java as much as possible

Comment: removing content of the first frame or remove first frame?

Comment: ya the content of first frame. But I've done it by removing the frame itself as i'm not much familiar

Comment: With content you mean the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look i figured out how it is to be done.

```
        import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class test extends Frame implements ActionListener   {
        Button b1;
        Label l1;
        static Frame f1,f2;

        public test()   {
            Panel p1 = new Panel();
            p1.add ( b1 = new Button("click") );
            p1.setLayout (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER) );
            add(p1);

            b1.addActionListener(this);
            addWindowListener ( new WindowAdapter() {
                                    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we)  {
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                               );
        }

        public test(int i)  {
            Panel p1 = new Panel();
            p1.add(l1 = new Label("new"));
            p1.setLayout (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER));
            add(p1);

            addWindowListener ( new WindowAdapter() {
                                    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we)  {
                                        System.exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                               );
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String s = ae.getActionCommand();
            if (ae.getSource() instanceof Button)   {
                if (s.equals("click"))  {
                    frame_invisible();
                    f2 = new test(10);
                    f2.setVisible(true);
                    f2.setSize(400,400);
                }
            }
        }

        public void frame_invisible()   {
            f1.setVisible(false);
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            f1 = new test();
            f1.setVisible(true);
            f1.setSize(400,400);
        }
    }
```